# How to add a Library Project to a android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt, library-project

I have created a new android project. I want to have a action bar at the top so I downloaded the [**Action Bar for Android Library**](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) because I want to support devices from android 2.1.

The description says

> The action bar component is an Library Project. This means that there's no need to 
>   copy-paste resources into your own project, simply
>   add the action bar component as a reference to any project.

I am new to android so what does this mean? How can I add the library to my existing project?

Import the library into your eclipse workspace:

- File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace, Next
- Select root directory: /path/to/project
- Projects->Select All

At this point it fails because there is nothing to select and the next button is deactivated.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `In your layout` section of the github link is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Created a Video Tutorial on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jK-5zqb_nQ

Answer (score 120, accepted):

1. File->New->Other
2. Select Android Project
3. Select "Create Project from existing source"
4. Click "Browse..." button and navigate to johannilsson-android-actionbar\actionbar
5. Finish (Now action bar project in your workspace)
6. Right-click on your project -> Properties
7. In Android->Library section click Add
8. select recently added project -> Ok
9. that's it!

Now you can use it

Comment: But now you have to have the library project open in your workspace any time you want to work on the dependent project right? Isn't that awkward?

Comment: if your library project doesn't appear in the `Android->Library->Add` list, go to `Android->Library` of your library project, and make sure "is Library" is checked

Comment: also be sure that library has a check in Properties isLibrary=checked

Answer (score 9):

Checkout this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) on how to reference a library project in eclipse.

From the link above:

1. In the Package Explorer, right-click the dependent project and select Properties.
2. In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
3. Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.
4. From the list of available library projects, select a project and click OK.
5. When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.
6. Click OK to close the Properties window.

Comment: at 4 the dialog is empty, there is no library listed

Comment: you have to import the library into your eclipse workspace first. See this post for how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse

Comment: i am having same problem as artworkad mentioned but Kurtis i tried ur way and its still showing me nothing

Answer (score 1):

Plus to the "best answer", at **step 8**, if you **don't see the project**, go to the project what you would like to add as a library and

- open 'project.properties'
- add '***android.library=true***'

and you can again follow the instruction and you should see the desirable project.