# android horizontal view paging indicator

Tags: android, paging, indicator

I've implemented the horizontal view paging, now how do i give the indicators. In a post i found a component com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator. But while executing it shows class not found. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For viewPager library is available at github.
Just use that lib and jar in your app. so that u can get CirclePageIndicator.

Comment: i'm facing probs in doing this. Can you please give the steps.

Comment: It asks to reference as library project. But im not able to do it.

Comment: right click on project folder, choose properties,there choose android, below click add button to add library.

Comment: u have to add that library to ur workspace then it will come there in the list

Comment: I followed the steps in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project)  and was able to add actionbar library to my project. But when I tried the same thing for view pager indicator browsing from 'JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator-3db7585\library', its not listing in the library to add.

Comment: did u add that jar to the build path of that library?

Comment: which jar? i cannot find any jar files with it

Comment: I downloaded the zip file from [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). I cant find the jar file in it. Please give me the path.

Comment: JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator-3db7585/ library/ libs/ android-support-v4.jar

Comment: the mistake i did was missing the isLibrary checkbox of the library project.