# Zoom-pan for ImageView from url

Tags: android, url, imageview, zooming, pan

Firstly, I want to say, that I am not strong at Android. I am trying to add zooming and panning to my application.

Here, I am using this tutorial to load my image from url and show it as ImageView.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

I've found this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/multi-touch-panning-pinch-zoom-image-view-in-android-using/ how to zoom and pan my image, but I don't really know, how I must change code from first tutorial, to get ImageView, which I could zoom and pan.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Take a look at [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView). It's an extremely easy to use library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) from ChrisBanes for the pan and zoom functionality
2. To load the image from a url into the PhotoView(ImageView) use the [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library.

I have used them together in a couple of apps and they work great together :)

Comment: Can you little explain how to use UniversalImageLoader with PhotoView together? :)

Comment: Umm in your xml file, use the PhotoView instead of the ImageView and in the java code, just copy any sample from imageviewloader and replace the imageview with your photoview and it will work all fine. If you need any code, do let me know.

Comment: I've added library to my project, changed in xml and my code ImageView to PhotoView. I want to run my project as application and I get error "Android libary projects cannon be launched." Maybe I did something wrong with adding library? I've just copied all library file content to my project.

Comment: No, that is not how you add a library project. Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8281477/1149279) link to see how to add library projects, and then we can move forward.

Comment: Thank you! All work great :) Had problem with xml. I changed to PhotoView, but needed to uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView :D Thank you one more time :)

Comment: @mzfx Accept it as an answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: I have one more question :) I am on another computer right now, so can't test it. Is it possible to use PhotoView with .pdf file type? Or maybe there is another library to zoom and pan .pdf file from url?

Comment: i think you can open the .pdf files in a webview and it provides the pan zoom functionality.

Comment: Maybe you can write a code, how to make it? I need to load .pdf from url like PhotoView. Really sorry, I have never used webview =/

Comment: Interesting that one of my friends can't see the image which was loaded in my app (I am using PhotoView). He is using LG x4 with 4.1.2 Android version. The images are loaded in his memory and he can see them by file manager, but in my app not.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code..


/**
 * Author  : Ramesh R
 * Created : 11/25/13 10:11 PM
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Copyright © EMD Systems Software Private Ltd.  All rights reserved.
 * This file is subject to the terms and conditions defined in
 * file 'LICENSE.txt', which is part of this source code package.
 * All other rights reserved.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

package com.emdsys.android.pacs.viewer.model;

import com.emdsys.android.pacs.R;
import com.emdsys.android.pacs.activity.TabActivityPacs;
import com.emdsys.android.pacs.activity.ViewerActivity;
import com.emdsys.android.pacs.shared.Config;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.view.VelocityTrackerCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.VelocityTracker;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

@SuppressLint("Recycle")
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

    private Matrix mMatrix;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    public static Rect startBounds;
    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;
    public static float startScaleFinal;
    public static int tab_check = 0;
    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;
    public int touchActionDownX = 0;
    public int touchActionDownY = 0;
    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    GestureDetector hidingevent;
    private int check = 0;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker = null;
    Context context;
    int pre_x = 0, pre_y = 0;
    public int check_for_unwanted = 0;
    private static Animator mCurrentAnimator;
    private static int mShortAnimationDuration = 500;
    public static TouchImageView full_image;
    public static View maintainView;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        TouchImageView.tab_check = 0;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        hidingevent = new GestureDetector(context, new singleTablistener());
        mMatrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                maintainView = v;
                hidingevent.onTouchEvent(event);
                if (ViewerActivity.sClick == 1) {
                    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX,
                                    viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY,
                                    viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                            mMatrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                    }

                    setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
                    invalidate();
                    return true; // indicate event was handled
                } else {
                    //
                    // Drag motion of the image view is achieved here.....
                    //
                    int index = event.getActionIndex();
                    int action = event.getActionMasked();
                    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);
                    switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                            // Retrieve a new VelocityTracker object to watch
                            // the
                            // velocity of a motion.
                            mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                        } else {
                            // Reset the velocity tracker back to its initial
                            // state.
                            mVelocityTracker.clear();
                        }
                        // Add a user's movement to the tracker
                        touchActionDownX = (int) event.getX();
                        touchActionDownY = (int) event.getY();
                        pre_x = (int) event.getX();
                        pre_y = (int) event.getY();
                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);

                        mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);

                        Log.d("", "DownX: " + touchActionDownX);
                        Log.d("", "DownY: " + touchActionDownY);
                        // On touch point identification..
                        int New_x = (int) event.getX();
                        int New_y = (int) event.getY();
                        //
                        // velocity of the pointer movement in the display...
                        //
                        int Velocityx = Math.abs((int) VelocityTrackerCompat
                                .getXVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId));
                        int Velocityy = Math.abs((int) VelocityTrackerCompat
                                .getYVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId));
                        if ((Math.abs(New_x - pre_x) > 3)
                                || (Math.abs(New_y - pre_y) > 3)) {
                            ViewerActivity.sDiffx = ((pre_x - New_x) / 3);
                            ViewerActivity.sDiffy = ((pre_y - New_y) / 3);

                            if ((ViewerActivity.sDiffx >= 0)
                                    && (ViewerActivity.sDiffy >= 0)) {
                                if (check == 0) {
                                    ViewerActivity.selecting_mode(Velocityx,
                                            Velocityy, 1);
                                    Log.d("", "Loop1");
                                    check++;
                                } else {
                                    check = 0;
                                }

                            } else if ((ViewerActivity.sDiffx <= 0)
                                    && (ViewerActivity.sDiffy >= 0)) {
                                if (check == 0) {
                                    ViewerActivity.selecting_mode(Velocityx,
                                            Velocityy, 1);
                                    Log.d("", "Loop1");
                                    check++;
                                } else {
                                    check = 0;
                                }
                            } else if ((ViewerActivity.sDiffx <= 0)
                                    && ViewerActivity.sDiffy <= 0) {
                                if (check == 0) {
                                    ViewerActivity.selecting_mode(Velocityx,
                                            Velocityy, 1);
                                    Log.d("", "Loop1");
                                    check++;
                                } else {
                                    check = 0;
                                }

                            } else if ((ViewerActivity.sDiffx >= 0)
                                    && ViewerActivity.sDiffy <= 0) {
                                if (check == 0) {
                                    ViewerActivity.selecting_mode(Velocityx,
                                            Velocityy, 1);
                                    Log.d("", "Loop1");
                                    check++;
                                } else {
                                    check = 0;
                                }
                            } else {
                                // Nothing is executing here....
                            }
                        }

                        pre_x = New_x;
                        pre_y = New_y;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        check_for_unwanted = 1;
                        // if(TouchImageView.tab_check!=1)
                        // {
                        //
                        // }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        // mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                        if (check_for_unwanted == 1) {
                            ViewerActivity.update_image(111);
                        } else {
                            ViewerActivity.selecting_mode(0, 0, 0);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }
            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                    || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                mMatrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                        viewHeight / 2);
            else
                mMatrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                        detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            // creation of reset button in viewer
            if ((viewHeight > ViewerActivity.sResetHeight)
                    && (viewWidth > ViewerActivity.sResetWidth)) {
                ViewerActivity.sResetImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                ViewerActivity.sResetImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        mMatrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            mMatrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
        // visibility of the image reset button...

    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        //
        // Rescaled image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            // Fit to screen.
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                    || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            mMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                    - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                    - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            mMatrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }

    public class singleTablistener implements OnDoubleTapListener,
            OnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

            if (ViewerActivity.sHide == 0) {
                TouchImageView.tab_check = 1;
                TabActivityPacs.tabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                TabActivityPacs.recorder_Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                TabActivityPacs.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                TabActivityPacs.playerloyout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                TabActivityPacs.Tab_whole.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) ViewerActivity.sImage)
                        .getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                zoomImageFromThumb(ViewerActivity.sImage, bitmap);
                ViewerActivity.sHide = 1;
                return true;
            } else {
                if (TouchImageView.mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                    TouchImageView.mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
                }

                // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
                // back to their original values.
                AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                set.play(
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                                TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView, View.X,
                                TouchImageView.startBounds.left))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                                TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView, View.Y,
                                TouchImageView.startBounds.top))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                                TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView,
                                View.SCALE_X, TouchImageView.startScaleFinal))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                                TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView,
                                View.SCALE_Y, TouchImageView.startScaleFinal));
                set.setDuration(TouchImageView.mShortAnimationDuration);
                set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        TouchImageView.full_image.setAlpha(1f);
                        TabActivityPacs.tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        TabActivityPacs.Tab_whole.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if (Config.sUserType.equalsIgnoreCase("radiologist")) {
                            TabActivityPacs.recorder_Layout
                                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            TabActivityPacs.playerloyout
                                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        TabActivityPacs.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView
                                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView)
                                .getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            ViewerActivity.sImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } else {
                            ViewerActivity.sImage
                                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultimage);
                        }

                        TouchImageView.mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        full_image.setAlpha(1f);
                        TabActivityPacs.tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        TabActivityPacs.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        TabActivityPacs.Tab_whole.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if (Config.sUserType.equalsIgnoreCase("radiologist")) {
                            TabActivityPacs.recorder_Layout
                                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            TabActivityPacs.playerloyout
                                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView
                                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView)
                                .getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            ViewerActivity.sImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } else {
                            ViewerActivity.sImage
                                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultimage);
                        }

                        TouchImageView.mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }
                });
                set.start();
                TouchImageView.mCurrentAnimator = set;
                ViewerActivity.sHide = 0;
                return true;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private void zoomImageFromThumb(final TouchImageView thumbView,
            Bitmap imageResId) {
        // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
        // immediately and proceed with this one.
        if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
            mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
        }
        full_image = thumbView;
        // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
        try {
            if (imageResId != null) {
                TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView.setImageBitmap(imageResId);
            } else {
                TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView
                        .setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultimage);
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.d(null, " Error " + exception);
        }

        // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
        // This step involves lots of math. Yay, math.
        TouchImageView.startBounds = new Rect();
        final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
        final Point globalOffset = new Point();

        // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
        // and the final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the
        // container
        // view. Also set the container view's offset as the origin for the
        // bounds, since that's the origin for the positioning animation
        // properties (X, Y).
        full_image.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
        TabActivityPacs.host.getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
        startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
        finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

        // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
        // bounds using the "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable
        // stretching during the animation. Also calculate the start scaling
        // factor (the end scaling factor is always 1.0).
        float startScale;
        if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > (float) startBounds
                .width() / startBounds.height()) {
            // Extend start bounds horizontally
            startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
            float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
            float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
            startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
            startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
        } else {
            // Extend start bounds vertically
            startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
            float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
            float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
            startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
            startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
        }

        // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
        // begins, it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the
        // thumbnail.
        full_image.setAlpha(0f);
        TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations
        // to the top-left corner of the zoomed-in view (the default
        // is the center of the view).
        TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
        TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

        // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
        // scale properties (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView,
                        View.X, startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView,
                        View.Y, startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView,
                        View.SCALE_X, startScale, 1f))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(TabActivityPacs.expandedImageView,
                        View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
        set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }
        });
        set.start();
        mCurrentAnimator = set;

        // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down
        // to the original bounds and show the thumbnail instead of
        // the expanded image.
        startScaleFinal = startScale;
    }

}
```