# Adding library project to PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, eclipse, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm trying to use 
[Android PagerSlidingTabStrip v1.0.1](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/releases/tag/v1.0.1)library

in my project but, after I import the project as existing code in work space  I get to project 
the `Mainactivity` and  `library` and and the `library` is a dependency to the `Mainactivity`

but it seems that library project doesn't recognized as local library

so what i did is

1- I tried to make a jar file called `library.jar` from the `library` project 
and I imported as a external jar so that fixed my import but when I try to use  `PagerSlidingTabStrip` object it says missing reference
and beside that there is `res` folder couldn't be loaded .

2- I follow this [How to add a Library Project to a android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project) 
and I did like what the accepted answer said but it still didn't work for me .

This is how I added the library project
[image: adding library project]

That what I got in project libraries 
[image: missing jar from bin folder in the library]

I tried to use this dependency in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
}
```

but it didn't work

i added before `sherlock` to eclipse so when i added it inside the root folder 
a bin folder created and inside it there are a jar file and that's 
doesn't happen with library so i think here is the problem

any help?

Answer (score 0):

From properties window select option android scroll down, below library heading click the add button and select library project.

Comment: thats what i did in 2 and the link i provided for adding library in that way

Comment: why it didn't work for you? after clicking add button did you get option for library project?

Comment: Try to keep both library and mainactivity project in the same workspace.

Comment: what is the error you are getting using that method?

Comment: i can't import it  The import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but soon i came to know that there was support library missing from Library project.

Add support library and clean build the library project and then add it in your project

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. File->New->Other
2. Select Android Project
3. Select "Create Project from existing source"
4. Click "Browse..." button and navigate to "PagerSlidingTabStrip-master" folder which you have downloaded from https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip
5. Check "library"! (Uncheck "sample"). Make sure "Copy to Workspace" is checked as well.
6. Click Finish. Now "library" is project in your workspace.
7. Right-click on your project -> Properties
8. In Android -> Library section, click "Add"
9. Select recently added "library" project, click Ok and you're all set.