# Android - include library project into main project

Tags: android, android-activity

i am trying to use the Tess-two OCR library the problem is that i have Tess two as a separate project and the main project is separate . what i want to do is to run my main project on the device which uses the Tess two library project what should i do in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Original Question and Answer: [How to add a Library Project to a android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project)

**Answer from above:**

1) File->New->Other

2) Select Android Project

3) Select "Create Project from existing source"

4) Click "Browse..." button and navigate to johannilsson-android-actionbar\actionbar

5) Finish (Now action bar project in your workspace)

6) Right-click on your project -> Properties

7) In Android->Library section click Add

8) select recently added project -> Ok

that's it!
Now you can use it

Answer (score 0):

whats a meaning of :

Click "Browse..." button and navigate to johannilsson-android-actionbar\actionbar

?
i not understand it