# How do I create a library project in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been having some difficulties over the past couple of days and can't seem to get it working. I'm trying to add the zbar library to my project:

https://github.com/dm77/ZBarScanner

Can anyone guide me through the process? Thanks!

Comment: here, hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project

Comment: That library is no longer being maintained. [The replacement library](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) can be retrieved through `compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.6'` in your `dependencies` closure in `build.gradle`.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

The key is to add a dependency from the application project, in the ÷build.gradle÷ file:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile project(':Zbar_Project_Name')
}
```

And, in the IntelliJ Module file, `??.iml`:

```
<orderEntry type="library" name="android-support-v4" level="application" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="Zbar_Project_Name.aar" level="project" />
```

In the library project, there’s not much to do: tell Gradle and Android Studio that this is an Android library, with apply plugin:

`android-library`

and

```
<option name=”LIBRARY_PROJECT” value=”true” />
```

respectively.