# How to add google play services libarary?

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to install google play service library for my android project. I am using ADT version 22.3.0. But, the problem is that **'Google Play Services Library'** is not available under 'Extras' in SDK Manager. And when I open ecllipse after updating SDK tools to latest version, eclipse give me error:
**" This android sdk requires ADT version 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 22.3.0. Please update ADT to latest version."**
And when I check for updates, then it says no updates available. Can one please help me.

Comment: uninstall and install again your `ADT` ,

Comment: I tried this, nothing happens

Comment: have u uninstall adt from eclipse

Comment: u can also use this one https://github.com/ErNaveen/google-play-services_lib

Comment: Yes, I uninstall ADT from eclipse, and after that I lost my eclipse .

Comment: play store lib for u https://github.com/ErNaveen/google-play-services_lib

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar How, can I use this in my android project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project

Answer (score 0):

```
I uninstall ADT from eclipse, and after that I lost my eclipse
```

Restart your eclipse, and updating SDK tools to latest version, then under Extra tab you install google-play library