# Difference between Importing a Project and Library in android

Tags: java, android, project, android-library

I have to **use A Project in B project**. I tried two techniques

1. Convert A Project to Library and include it to B Project and also
   **checked** `Android Private Libraries` under `Project Properties->Java Build Path->Order And Export`
2. Add `A Project to B Project` without converting it to `Library`.And
   also check Project under `Order and Export`

Both of them giving me Error `NoDefinationFound` and `NoClassFound`(Whether you declare it in `manifest.xml`) respectively.

I want to know what is the `difference between these approach` and where am i `doing wrong`.

I know I can `copy all resource and Packages` of **Project A to Project B**.But why this `technique not working`.

> And what are the major Advantage of using one Approach over another

I know both ways to import Project and Library. But still NoClassDefinitionError and ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project

Comment: Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: @Xcihnegn I am using Eclipse

Comment: @PankajKumar i have import it in the same way as you said. but how can i get rid of Errors

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about the difference between both approach

But for Including A Project to B Project :

You should follow this steps :

> Right click B Project -> Open Properties -> Click on Java Build Path
>   -> Goto Project Tab -> Click Add -> Add A Project -> This way you have included JAR of A Project in B Project

I am also want to know difference between these two approach

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

1. Project A->Properties->Android: under `Library`, check `is Library`
2. Project B->Properties->Android: under `Library`, press `Add`, choose `Project A` to add as library

Hope this help!