# Using open source libraries in Android projects

Tags: android, github, libraries, code-organization

I'm a beginner in Android programing, and I'm working with android studio...now i wander what is the best way for installing open sources libraries from gitHub.
my question is from organization principles point of view-
should i create a new package for every library and put all the library source code as is in that package? should the package be in the source.main.java folder?? (the one that the android studio creates automaticly).
sorry for the dumb question...it's just that im taking my first baby steps in a big scale program and i don't want to loose my head in the future because of bad organization practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no right answer to this question. A few wrong ways to do it, but common sense will guide you.

My advice:

Start by having the source of this open source code checked into your company's source control system somewhere and capable of being built or re-built as needed. Not necessarily in your project, but just getting the code checked in so it can't be lost or confused with the original author's ever evolving changes on GitHub.

As to how you consume it, you have several options.

1. Build the open source in it's own project (checked into source control, but separate from your main project). Then just take the drop of compiled files (.class, .jar, .lib, etc...) and check that into your main project.  This is the most flexible option if you don't think you are ever going to need to change the open source code that often. Has the side benefit of being managed for several projects.
2. Drop the source code as-is directly into your project. This means you will always be rebuilding the code. This gives the most flexibility with evolving and changing the the code specific to your project needs.

There's probably hybrid solutions of these options as well.

The bottom line is that whatever you use needs to be copied and building in your own system. Because the code you pulled down from GitHub could go away or change significantly at any time.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to use [JitPack](https://jitpack.io) to import those GitHub projects into your gradle build.

First you need to add the repository:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

and then all the GitHub repositories as dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.RepoOwner:Repo:Version'
    // more dependencies...
}
```

Behind the scenes JitPack will check out the code and compile it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/796400/). If you are using eclipse, you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8281477/796400)

If you are looking for adding jar file to your lib, you can simply create a lib folder in your project and add jar file into the library and you must add the line `compile files('jarfile.jar')` in the build file(gradle build). If you are using eclipse you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1337933/796400/)

By the way, creating a package for each library and putting all library source codes doesn't look sane to me. It is almost equivalent to recreating the project. I'm sure that it is not the proper approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the third-party code is packaged as a .jar or a .aar and made available in public-facing maven repository (e.g. maven central), then you should add the library as a dependency in your build.gradle file.

If it is not available as a maven/gradle dependency, you could add the library's code to your project  as suggested in other answers here. I have never liked that solution at all.

You could also build the .jar or .aar and add that to your project's lib directory, as also suggested by other answers here. For a small, simple project with few dependencies, that might make sense.

What I like to do for larger, longer-lived projects, is to set up my own Nexus server (a Maven repo server), and put the third-party dependencies there.

Comment: thanks! i didn't got the Nexus server thing but im not aiming for that scale of projects yet...