# Android modify imported library via gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am imported the zxing android library for use via gradle, however I want to modify the way things are drawn. From my understanding, that can only be changed by changing the draw function in one of the classes in the library. The problem is I cannot modify the classes in the library due to them being imported with gradle.

Is there any way I can edit that file or even supply another file to override that one? Thanks for your time.

Edit:
Here is a link to the zxing github and the class that I am trying to change the functions in. I want to be able to change what the onDraw function does.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/ViewfinderView.java

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: I have updated the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a way to override the file, but I did find a workaround. I ended up extending the zXingScannerView file and did an override for the function setAutoFocus(boolean state). I chose that one because it was always called after the overlay was set and allowed me to easily remove it straight away.

Inside that funtion I did:

```
int chidrenCount = getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
    if(getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewFinderView) {
        getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help @FlyingPumba

Answer (score 0):

if you refer to the [Zxing Android library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) for working with Barcodes, it's Open Source !
That means you can download the source code of this library, import it to your project and make the changes you need.

For reading more on importing libraries to Android projects, read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331659/using-open-source-libraries-in-android-projects).

Also, if you feel that other users of ZXing would benefit from this change, you can always contribute to the library on [GitHub](https://github.com/zxing/zxing).

Comment: I use Gradle dependencies `compile 'name'` to add a library, because it is fast and easy. But often, I need to edit a couple of lines of the external library for debugging/testing purposes. It seems Gradle already has  cached source files of it (I am sure the file I see in Android Studio is not a decompiled version, because it contains comments inside methods). Isn't there an easier way to do that other than downloading the source files again and manually add them to my project and remove the dependency?