# Using third party library in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-eclipse

I am new to android and I wanted to use some 3rd party API.

For that i need gradle installed ?

If yes, What all things does gradle covers.. ?
Can Anyone guide me how to cover it for android using Eclipse ?

Comment: to use gragle you need to download Android studio

Comment: What is that Gradle integration with Eclipse,i usually find on google ?

Comment: Android Studio come out with the Gradle. And usually people use Ant for Eclipse.

Comment: Can you suggest me some example for guidance ?

Comment: I want to include this in my project https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question have been asked before in here -> [How to add a Library Project to a android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project)

1.)File->New->Other

2.)Select Android Project

3.)Select "Create Project from existing source"

4.)Click "Browse..." button and navigate to your project

5.)Finish (Now action bar project in your workspace)

6.)Right-click on your project -> Properties

7.)In Android->Library section click Add

8.)select recently added project -> Ok