# How to add image buttons with ripple effect in cardview?

Tags: android, view, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm looking at implementing a cardview which has a button with the ripple effect.
I'm talking about something like this :
https://lh5.ggpht.com/uTRdkJMNyy3KasauJsyGTTRHn5EZBtmA3-BVHCaHWiqBIF_XQmJg_MuE8OdisvefdEk=h900-rw)

I'm trying to implement the download/share button as present on those cards.
Should I be using an ImageButton or something else?
Also, how can I extend the same support for pre-lollipop devices?

UPDATE:

This is the code I'm using right now. It gives me an image button but I'n not able to get touch/ripple effects. The android:foreground property works for cardView and gives the ripple effect, but not for ImageButton.

```
      <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_open_map"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_directions_grey600_36dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be interesting for you.
You will have to import or link the library to be able to use it.

Here is the link to the library : 
[Link to the library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/980)

It is easy to use and it is based on imageView.

Hope it helps you :) Let me know

**EDIT**
Editing my link for your update :)
Take a look at this : [MaterialRipple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple)

Comment: Hi, I'm not actually looking for something like this. Please check the update  in the question.

Comment: The links look promising. I'll check them out. Thanks. :)

Comment: How can include the RippleEffect library into my project?

Comment: If you are using android studio, it is easy : in you projet gradle file, you have to add new dependencies 
    `compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.4'`
else you will have to download the RippleEffect projet and add it to your project as a library as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8281477/3858220)

Comment: Good job glad to have helped you ;)