# compress file with zip4j on android

Tags: android, zip4j

I need to add files on a zip package but on the line code `zipFile.addFiles(filesToAdd, parameters)" the "addFiles()` appears in red, can anyone help me, please?

I'm using:

- Android Studio 1.2.1.1 RC
- Java 1.8 update 45
- Windows professional
- zip4j_1.3.2.jar (source: http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php)

image reference:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/HTfDOT1yZBb7k-oxLulCYukhBMv7xksHj2UhK-_YXSAkNmpQKkgdrSCJpa4T3cs1vWMNnHBWPxwkbKM=w1342-h513-rw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip file format is "native" in Java. Reading and writing those files are implemented out of the box by the java toolkit http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/

No need of add-ons.

Comment: Oh thanks. :)
you know if you can set a password to the zip file?

Comment: Zip Encryption is not supported by Java inbuilt zip implementation. Zip4j supports Zip encryption/decryption. I believe you have a library import issue. I suggest you have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project)