# Add Android color picker library to Project in Eclipse

Tags: android

I have just downloaded a project here
[Color Picker](https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna)

What should I do to add it to my Project and then use it

Im really stuck now. If you have the answer, plz show me step by step

Thanks in advance
!!!!

Comment: import it into your eclipse and add it to your project as a library

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute ‘supportsAlpha’ in package ‘yuku.ambilwarna.demo’

Comment: Check [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8281477/3022836](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8281477/3022836)

Comment: thks. i have added to my workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the project as existing android code into workspace in eclipse and add it as library to your project.

Comment: when i import. there are 2 project inside: main & AmbilWarnaDemoActivity. Both have errors: No resource identifier found for attribute ‘supportsAlpha’ in package ‘yuku.ambilwarna.demo’ (AmbilWarna....),  No resource identifier found for attribute ‘layerType’ in package ‘android’ (main)

Comment: It may be because it needed `Appcompact` library and check properties, you have to mark it as a library too.

Comment: i use 'main' as the library for my project but Ctr+Shift+0: can not import needing library