# How to use Ripple effect to below lollipop version?

Tags: android, rippledrawable

I want to use Ripple effect to my app, but i read a review which is only applicable for 5.0 and above. Then how to use ripple library to below 5.0?

Comment: use Material design library ..

Comment: @Destro ripple effect is not available in design library. Try this https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect. kabil dev Please try and search in Google first.

Comment: Recently i download "Library for Developers" app from google play. They used those effects on below lollipop versions. I need to know how they done. I'm new for this concept. So please post your answer's...

Comment: @Boss i have downloaded that Ripple Effect file. But i don't know how to import this library to my eclipse and use to my app. Please post brief answer...

Comment: You should look deeper in the code. You will understand. Basically `CustomView` is used for that.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use ripple libraries. For example [this](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) one. Just copy its dependency to build.gradle of project and then wrap your view that needs ripple effect by this code in xml:

Read its readme file to undrstand better

Comment: i'm using eclipse and i have downloaded RippleEffect library through github.com. After that i don't know how to use this library and how to import into eclipse...

Comment: @kabil dev http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project

Comment: Just add the library to your project and its ready to use, then follow instructions of library to learn how to use